# mysql query not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table

one is name game

```
id      name   area  end_date

1      first  14,13  2014-07-25

2      second  15    2014-07-25
```

Another table name area

```
id   name

13  one_area
14  two_area
15  three_area

$today='2014-07-20';(write it to understand query use CURRENT_DATE())
```

now I have a select box here i want to show area list which are not in game table or if exist in game table the this game end date is less then today.

my query

```
select a.* from area as a  where a.id NOT IN (
            SELECT area FROM game
                WHERE date(end_date)>CURRENT_DATE())
```

it gives result of area id is 13

But it will be no result cause 14,13 no area added in 1 no game and both end date is not less then today

Comment: value `14,13` treated as string value for query like `where id in ('14,13')` and you expecting it like `where id in ('14','13')`.. so it will not work as you expected

Comment: You have to use `FIND_IN_SET` to search for an element in a comma-separated list.

Comment: i am trying with FIND_IN_SET but no work

select a.* from area as a  where a.id FIND_IN_SET(NOT IN (
            SELECT area FROM game
                WHERE date(end_date)>CURRENT_DATE()))  
@Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM area AS a
LEFT JOIN game AS g ON FIND_IN_SET(a.id, g.area) AND DATE(g.end_date) > CURRENT_DATE()
WHERE g.id IS NULL
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69b5c/9)